# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have two projects called **A** and **B**. Now, i have one service class in **B** project and inside the service class, i have one endpoint like below:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class ReportAPIService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

Now, i want to call this endpoint from another WebAPI project and which is **A**. So, to achieve this, at first i ran the **B** project locally in my environment. Then, added a service reference of the **ReportAPIService** in my **A** project and it has been added successfully. I gave the service address as below:

> http://localhost:4043/ReportAPIService/ReportAPIService.asmx

Then, i added below code to call the endpoint in project **A**.

```
ReportAPIServiceSoapClient soapClient = new ReportAPIServiceSoapClient();        
return soapClient.HelloWorld();
```

But, it gives me the below error when trying to initialize **ReportAPIServiceSoapClient()**:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that
>   references contract 'ReportService.ReportAPIServiceSoap' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.

*What should i have to add in the client configuration section?*

Then, i tried with `HTTPClient` like below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4043/ReportAPIService/ReportAPIService.asmx/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("HelloWorld");
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But, stuck at the `GetAsync` method. No response from the server.

web.config in WCF service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ReportAPIServiceSoap" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:4043/ReportAPIService/ReportAPIService.asmx"
 binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportAPIServiceSoap"
 contract="ReportService.ReportAPIServiceSoap" name="ReportAPIServiceSoap" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Is there any other way to call a endpoint of a project from an another project in ASP.NET?

Comment: error is pretty clear as it says there is no matching endpoint defined. Post the web.config file for your WCF service

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks wrong to me. A simplified one looks like below. See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/simplified-configuration-for-wcf-services) for more information

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>  
      <service name="<Provide Fully qualified service name>">  
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4043/ReportAPIService/ReportAPIService.asmx"
                   binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ReportService.ReportAPIServiceSoap"/>  
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>  
      </service>  
    </services> 
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: what will be the fully qualified service name? I didn't get this part.

Comment: I have added this but still getting the same error.